# DocuSign: What API endpoint or method is used to retrieve a list of power forms stored in the account?

Tags: docusignapi

I asked similar question, but docusign support said post our question to stackoverflow again.

My prevuis question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152052/docusign-how-to-get-power-forms-from-api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not currently a way for REST to return this information, I believe it is in the plans to be released, I'm just not sure when.

SOAP does not have this functionality, and I don't think it's planned to add as a feature either.

When it is supported in REST the path should be:
`GET https://{server}/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/powerforms`